# Scala Nested Functions/High-Order Functions

Tags: scala, function, nested, fibonacci

I'm new to Scala and have recently just been introduced to how functions work in the language.

I'm trying to calculate phi using a fibonacci function. The two fibonacci functions were easy enough to write (one recursive and one tail-recursive), but I am at a complete loss as to how to proceed.

From my understanding the function golden will use the result of the function fib as a parameter, and then integer n to determine the precision. However despite researching for some time now I'm at a complete loss as to how to accomplish this.

I need to use individual F1 and F2 parameters to calculate phi surely? So should I add more variables to my fib function to do so and calculate during the fibonacci calculation?

That aside, how do I enforce precision to x amount of digits?

Below is the screenshot of what I have so far, I'd greatly appreciate any help you can offer. I'm really struggling to even begin to move forward on this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWOIq.png

```
// Fibonacci Sequence 1

def fib(n: Int): Int = {
while(n-1 > 0){
return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
}
  return n
}

fib(40)
assert(fib(40) == 102334155, "Wrong result for fib1(40)!")

// Fibonacci Sequence 2

def fib2(n: Int): Int = {
 def tailrec(f1: Int, f2: Int, n: Int): Int = {
  if(n != 1) {
    tailrec(f2, f2 + f1, n-1)
   }
     else {
       return f2
     }
  }
   return tailrec(0, 1, n)
 }

 fib2(40)
 assert(fib2(40) == 102334155, "Wrong result for fib1(40)!")

 // Write a function that returns the φ value with at least n digits of precision

 def golden(fib: Int => Int, n: Int): Double = {
   return (fib(n) / fib(n+1))
 }

 golden(fib(_), 40)
```

Comment: Is this for a class?  Here are a few hints:  In golden(), the type of the fib parameter is "Int => Int", a function which accepts an integer and produces an integer, which matches the type of your fib() method.  This implies that you will pass your fib method as a parameter to golden().  golden() can use this fib function internally, and will need to loop until it finds a sufficiently precise estimate.

Comment: How would I calculate phi though? I'd need to rewrite fib surely?

Comment: You don't need to rewrite fib.  You only need to use fib.  For example, phi1 = fib(10) / fib(9) is an approximation of phi.  phi2 = fib(11) / fib(10) is a slightly better approximation of phi.  It's up to you to figure out how many iterations of fib you will need to obtain the required precision.

Comment: def golden(fib: Int => Int, n: Int): Double = {
  return fib(n) / fib(n-1)
}

One thing; how do I test this? I keep getting a type error when i try to use the function like I previously did.

Basically I get type (Int) => Int expected, actual: Int

Comment: A few specific comments on the code: in the first `fib` function, I think you mean `if`, not `while`. And normal Scala code almost never uses `return`, so you should remove all your uses of it.

Comment: One more comment: "I keep getting a type error when i try to use the function like I previously did" — it's hard to help you when you only describe your code in English. Please include the actual code you tried and the actual type error you got. Code doesn't really fit in comments, but you can edit your question to include code. Not a screenshot of the code — paste in the actual code.

Comment: Okay sorry, I've added in my latest code there now.

I am getting a result but it's not accurate, it just returns a double of 1.0

I've tried tweaking the n values but nothing seems to do it so far. Naturally I'm working with the formula to calculate phi here which should be just F(n+1) / F(n) but that doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere.

Does scala do any automatic rounding?

Comment: What's weird is that fib(n+1) returns 1.65580141E8 and fib(n) returns 1.023341 which seems correct. When I divide the though it seems to round it to 1.0??

Comment: You need to explicitly convert `fib(n)` and/or `fib(n + 1)` to `Double` before dividing, now you are doing division using `Int`s and then the result is converted to a `Double` (because the return type is `Double`).

Comment: Ahh sorry of course, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def golden(fib: Int => Int, n: Int): Double = {
def goldenCal(n: Int): Double = fib(n + 1).toDouble / fib(n).toDouble
def isGoodEn(n: Int, precision: Int): Boolean = Math.abs(goldenCal(n) - goldenCal(n + 1)) < (Math.pow(10, -(precision + 1)))
def goldenIter(n: Int, precision: Int): Double = {
if (isGoodEn(n, precision))
goldenCal(n + 1)
else
//calculate the golden number using fib1
goldenIter(n + 1, precision)
}
goldenIter(n, 3)
}
def golden1(n:Int):Double = golden(fib1,n)
golden1(9)
def golden2(n:Int):Double = golden(fib1,n)
golden1(5)
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: Thomas this is not the correct solution to the problem shown in your screenshot yet, although I don't feel right about giving you the answer to what seems to be your homework.  As a reminder, you are trying to produce an approximation within a given number of digits of precision.  The n parameter should represent this precision, not the number of fibonacci iterations.

Comment: Sorry yeh I've realized this now. Got massively confused and assumed that he meant precision as in better precision of phi as n increases. Instead that would be a better approximation as you said. If he had used something other than 'n' I might have caught that. :/

Will update the answer